# Visually in C# code what is the string literal?

Tags: c#, string-literals

I'm confused as to what exactly is a string literal in code.
In looking at the following code: `"Apple"`

Is `Apple` the string literal? (the pair of double quotes IS NOT considered part of a string literal)

Or is `"Apple"` the string literal? (the pair of double quotes IS considered part of a string literal)

Comment: Yes, the quotes [are](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#string-literals) a part of the literal.

Comment: The string literal is the *code/syntax representation* of the string character sequence (*including* quotes). Multiple literals may map to the same string character sequence even though they use different quotes or escapes.

Comment: Curious why it makes the slightest bit of difference? This is purely academic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the formal grammar here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#tokens

It is clear that string literal is defined as:

```
string_literal
    : regular_string_literal
    | verbatim_string_literal
    ;
regular_string_literal
    : '"' regular_string_literal_character* '"'
    ;
....
verbatim_string_literal
    : '@"' verbatim_string_literal_character* '"'
    ;
....
```

Or simply speaking, string literal is any token of either form "String" or @"String", so answering your questions - quotes are part of the literal.

Comment: The term "string literal" is strictly a *compilation time* term, it is the token identified by the compiler *front end* during the lexical analysis of the code, one of the first stages of the compilation. It can then be used to create an object of class string if you wish, but that it a later stage. When talking about *string literal* it is purely a lexical term, unrelated to its later possible uses.

Comment: Yes, regular or verbatim.